# Finding slope of a straight line using numpy polyfit, where some values are zero

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to calculate the slope of a graph like this.

x= [1,2,3,4,5] 
y= [1,0,5,0,8]

s, i = numpy.polyfit(np.log(x), np.log(y), 1)

But it is not working as there are some zeros in y list and log(y) is no number.
How can I find the slope using polyfit?

Comment: Side note, these points do not form a straight line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like the slope (agnostic to the quality of fit) after ignoring the zeros in list `y`, then this code should work -

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import compress

x= [1,2,3,4,5] 
y= [1,0,5,0,8]

# Create new lists which ignore the 0 indices in list y 
xLog = list(compress(np.log(x), np.log(y)>0))
yLog = list(compress(np.log(y), np.log(y)>0))

s, i = numpy.polyfit(xLog, yLog, 1)
```